# PineScript exiting trade conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, pine-script-v4

can you explain to me why my strategy doesn't close a trade when the condition for stop loss is hit? I want to exit the trade either when the current candle closes (which works), or if the stoploss is hit. I have set the stop loss to low[1] (the previous candles low).
Code below:
if barstate.isconfirmed or low <= stopLoss
strategy.close("Long")

Thanks!

Code below:
if barstate.isconfirmed or low <= stopLoss
strategy.close("Long")

expecting to close when previous candle low is broken

Answer (score -1):

Use `strategy.exit()` [function](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit)

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

var float stopLoss  = na

if close > open
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    stopLoss := low[1]

strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", stop = stopLoss)
```